# Active Users Prevent Files From Being Deleted As They're Using Those Files In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis

In my website, there are some images that are being used by some users. Those pictures set to some background image tags in the HTML file. There are no active streams that I've made and I'm completely sure about that, it's the web pages that are using those files.

I need to close users' active sessions and close all the file providing streams to update my website. Is there a way to do that? Like resetting IIS or something like that, that the server stops reading those images?

EDIT: My customer will need to communicate with APIs in order to make changes.

Comment: Stopping the IIS service will do that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The problem is that my customer still wants to communicate with website's APIs.

Comment: Usually users do not have permission to delete files, you just need to make sure that the user has read permission.

Comment: @samwu Yeah they don't. The fact is that the user is making the computer read an image and this will make the image un-deletable. I can't even delete it from the control panel. I think I have to put the site on under construction mode to be able to remove any of those images or files that are being used.